# Catchall Cname for use with Elastic Load Balancer AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cname, catch-all

I am using AWS's Elastic Load Balancer in my current setup which then passes requests to two application servers. I switched over to AWS within the past couple of months and am trying to figure out the best way to do a catchall in my Zone file so that any traffic to any other sub domain gets sent to the load balancer.

GoDaddy doesn't allow Cnames to use the * as a catchall and ELB does not have a public IP for me to point to; just the public DNS record that Amazon provides. How should I handle a catchall in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I would transfer the domain to AWS and use Route 53 [alias](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html)

Answer (score 0):

Route53 allows `*.rood.tld` `ALIAS A` records, which is exactly what you're trying to accomplish. `CNAME`s are illegal to put on the root (apex) of a domain, so you cannot use a domain name for the root of your domain (or the other subdomains with `*`), so you need an IP.

`ALIAS A` records are `A` records which are runtime-resolved by your DNS provider, meaning, while you specify within Route53 that the root of the domain points to another domain name (the ELB's host), when queried externally, the DNS system actually replies with the `A` record for the ELB, and thus all the required IPs.